# xpath of elemnts including same child

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to click publish report button so I use this `xpath->//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block']`.

I want to click that button who has `href='http://www.jbalbertos.com'`, means that xpath should be like this `//div/a[@href='http://www.jbalbertos.com/']` and `//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block']`

if any one knows kindly give me right xpath statement.

```
<div class="search-business-description">
            <div class="business-name ng-binding">J.B. Alberto's Pizza</div>
            <div class="business-address ng-binding">
            <div class="business-website">
                <span class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="getWebsite()"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.brchichago.com/">http://www.brchichago.com/</a>
    </span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="business-website">
                <span class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="getWebsite()"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.jbalbertos.com/">http://www.jbalbertos.com/</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="business-actions">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="onPublish(result)">
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly

```
//div[//a[@href='http://www.jbalbertos.com/']]/following-sibling::div[@class="business-actions"]/button[@class='btn btn-success btn-block']
```

Comment: you understood it very well (Y)
but it didnt work for me, it is still not clicking button